# Vue | Router navigate to another instance

Tags: vue.js, router

I have 2 Vue instances, one for the frontend and one for the admin side of things.

With this, I have 2 different routers which hold the different routes for navigating throughout the 2 Vue instances.

I'm wondering, if I have a centralised login, which sits within the frontend application, how do I go about navigating to the admin side once authenticated? I have tried the following methods:

```
@click="$router.push('/admin')"
```

```
import router from '../router';

export default {
    methods: {
        navigateToAdmin() {
            router.go('/admin'); // also tried router.push('/admin');
        }
    }
}
```

Both of these seem to do the same thing and push the url to the browser but they don't actually change the page, which is why I was wondering if it was possible to do this in a SPA.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to route to `/admin` page a user after login, you can try this:

```
@click="navigateToAdmin()"

navigateToAdmin() {
        // if login success
        this.$router.push('/admin'); // automatically routes to admin page
    }
```

---

If you going to `/admin` page manually;

```
<router-link to="/admin">Admin</router-link>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an unknown route with `<router-link>` or `router.push` because the router will fail to resolve it (since that route is not configured in the router).

You should use a regular  link